# How to copy maven artifacts from one repository to another

Tags: maven, copy, release, stage

How can I copy the maven artifacts from one repository to another? 
I create a release and I do not want to publish this release immediately. I want to leave it for some days as "internal" to test it. Later on, when all tests pass, I want to move these artifacts into a public release repository.

[maven-stage-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-stage-plugin/usage.html) is no longer maintained.

The release plugin would build a new release, but I want to use the same artifact, that has already been tested.

Comment: Which repository manager are you using?

Comment: Nexus repository manager

Comment: Which version? 2 or 3?

Comment: Version 3.19.1-01

Comment: So you don't trust your own unit- and integration tests. Apart from that this is called a staging strategy which can be done with Nexus Repo Manager but only with the commerical variant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks to me that you need CI environment which supports different pipelines.

Every commit/push should trigger a deployment on your DEV environment where you can test your application.
Upon tag the CI environment would trigger a different pipeline stage which can 'release' application/library.

The tag effectively snapshots your version and creates a distribution.

Comment: I have built exactly this. The release pipeline push the release artifacts to the stage repository. To test internal. Some tests cannot be easily automate and the product is some library, which is product itself. After this stage release we integrate this release to our other application uses this technology. When everything is ok, we want to publish this version. So now, i have to build another artifact and then upload to public repository. I would like to copy the existing artifact from stage repository to public. But i cannot find any tools which makes this.

Comment: When "build another artifact" do you mean rebuild the same one from the same source?

Comment: Yes, i mean, i have repeat the build process. I am a little bit paranoid, so i have looked for a some solution not to do it.

Comment: A natural process would be to build/deploy on DEV, test and when ready tag the source: upon tag the CI builds again (from the same source) and pushes to the public repository. You need to be confident that your rebuild from source is solid (but this is a very good practise).

If you really want to the publish the very same build already used on DEV then you probably need to store those artifacts somewhere (a WAR file in folder, a JAR file on a Maven repo) then build a custom step (ie copy files, deploy script) to publish those